# java.langArrayIndexoutofBoundsException how to solve this

Tags: java, netbeans

I have a Java application which has to connect with a SQL database. The code should allow the user to create a new account.
The user has to login to the application to do an operation.

#### My code

```
  String sql="select * from newaccount where Username = ? and password = ? ";
        try{
         pst=con.prepareStatement(sql);
         pst.setString(2, loginusername.getText());
           pst.setString(3,loginpass.getText());
       rs=pst.executeQuery();
            if(rs.next()){
                rs.close();
                pst.close();
                
                
                setVisible(false);
                lodding ld= new  lodding();
                ld.setVisible(true);
                
            }else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Username or password incorrect");
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }finally{
            try{
                                rs.close();

                pst.close();
                
            }catch(Exception e){

            }
            
        }
        
        
        
    }
```

#### database creating code

```
       try{
           String sql="Insert into newaccount(Name,Username,password,Email,secque,answer)"
                   + " values (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
           pst=con.prepareStatement(sql);
           pst.setString(1, namenew.getText());
           pst.setString(2, usernamenew.getText());
           pst.setString(3,pass.getText());
           pst.setString(4, email.getText());
           pst.setString(5, (String)jComboBox1.getSelectedItem());
           pst.setString(6, answernew.getText());
           pst.execute();
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "New Account Create");
                   
       }catch(Exception e){
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
           
       }
  
    }
```

When I run the code to create the database, the database is created successfully. However in the login step, it gives this error
this is an error image
[image]
and this is a database
[image]

> java.langArrayIndexoutofBounds2>

Comment: Please provide the full stack trace of the error message

Comment: At first query you have only two placeholders `?`, why then `pst.setString(3, ..)`?

Answer (score 0):

You did not set the actual values properly.
you only have two placeholders so you only need to set the value for indices 0 and 1 just like code below:

```
String sql="select * from newaccount where Username = ? and password = ? ";
pst=con.prepareStatement(sql);
pst.setString(0, loginusername.getText());
pst.setString(1,loginpass.getText());
```